# Какие микропаттерны программирования вы используете?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Я имею в виду шаблонные техники написания кода для решения определенных задач: например, в кэшировании данных мы используем мемоизацию, при валидации данных - так называемые "калитки" из условий из конструкций if/else на входе метода. К микропаттернам можно отнести и рекурсию, и принцип "разделяй и властвуй", т.е. то, что не относится к высокоуровневым шаблонам проектирования GoF, а применяется на более низком внутриклассовом уровне программирования.